# Two timers working on Concurrent Dictionary c#

Tags: c#

I have two timers which are working on the application. One is firing when a new message is received and that will be added to a Concurrent Dictionary. The other one is firing to remove any message(i.e. trying to get message) from the dictionary if that message is in the dictionary for 'x' time.

```
public class Program
{
   static void Main()
   { 
       string val;
       Console.Write("Enter Type: ");
       val = Console.ReadLine();

       int type = Convert.ToInt32(val);
       TimerExample.Start(type);
   }
}

static class TimerExample
{
   static Timer _timer;
   static Timer _timer2;
   static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Message> dict;
   static int _type;

   public static void Start(int type)
   {
       var timer = new Timer(3000);
       timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
       timer.Enabled = true;
       _timer = timer;

       var timer2 = new Timer(3000);
       timer2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer2_Elapsed);
       timer2.Enabled = true;
       _timer2 = timer2;
       _type = type;
   }

   static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
      _dict.Add(_type,DateTime.Now);
   }

   static void _timer2_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
      //remove here if type is stuck in the dict for more than 30 secs
   }
}
```

There can be multiple types as keys in the dict at one point of time so whenever the 2nd timer elapsed I have to check the time for each type in the dictionary it was there. If one or more than types are in the dict for more than 30 secs remove them from the dict.

My concern is whenever I am reading the dict the first timer can also add new time for already added type can that cause a consurrency problem? And the other question is whenever I got the message from the dict which was there for more than 30 secs for any type and at that time only timer1 also updated the new time for that type can that also cause a concurrency problem or data loss problem?

Any help?

Comment: I'm not really seeing why you need 2 timers? ConcurrentDictionary is atomic with regard to put/get so if your timerX reads type 1 "at the same time" timerY writes type1 then the time read will either be the old time or the new time (because nothing happens "at the same time" exactly)

Comment: If you are worried about the time being updated on an existing dictionary item, why would you update it? If you need each item added to be processed/removed after 30 seconds, then do not update the item with a new time. If that is the case, you probably do not want a `ConncurentDictionary` type, instead maybe a [ConcurrentBag](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead? Also, by their nature, these `Concurrent*` objects are threadsafe and meant for avoiding concurrency issues. So you should not have any problems.

Comment: @CaiusJard: So basically I havent added that but besides time we have another info also in the dict. So whenever any data gets added in the dict we dont usually process that data at that point of time some times we wait to get some more info related to that type. So what happens when for that type for a long time we didnt get any data that old data is still there for a long time. Thats why i implemented the second timer so that we can process the old data and it will not stuck for a long time.

Comment: You are making it harder then it needs to be.  Just don't remove anything, whomever retrieves the value can trivially tell that 30 seconds have passed from the retrieved value.  Also note that you are reinventing the MemoryCache class.

Comment: @HansPassant: It's not about removing. The main reason of doing this is that sometimes back to back we get same messages and i dont want to process the same message again and again. So for that whenever new message comes I am not processing it straight away but saving it in dict and checking whenever the new message is different from the old one in dict then only process the old one and add the new one in dictionary and so on. But sometimes new message will not come for a long time and this makes the old message stuck in the dictionary for a long time thats why I implemented 2nd timer

Comment: And it is a service which is waiting for messages using the first timer. And 2nd timer will check the last time any message got added in the dict if it is more than x secongs get that message and process that.

Comment: The same timer fires every 3 seconds and it can do 2 things: GetNewMessagesFromServiceAndAddToDictionary() and also IterateDictionaryAndLookForMessagesOlderThan30s() - this latter method is like `foreach(var m in dict.Values) if((DateTime.Now - m.CreatedDate).TotalSeconds > 30) …`

Comment: The first timer has very low interval time due to a use case. And i dont want that same low time to check the dictionary for expiration time. That was also one of the reason to create other timer to remove items from dictionary for processing.

Comment: OK, so make IterateDictionaryAndLookForMessagesOlderThan30s return instantly 9 times out of 10, class wide variable `if((_expiryCheck = _expiryCheck++ % 10) != 0 return`

Comment: @CaiusJard: So you are saying create some counter and if its value is from 0 to 9 return instantly and when counter reached at 10th index start removing values?

Comment: It's a trick I often use to have a single timer ona  low interval (1 second) kick off multiple different actions at different intervals  - every minute, poll X, every 5 minutes, flush to the DB. Saves on Timers, just has ints that roll around due to the mod operator.

Comment: @CaiusJard: Can u give me an example of that one-timer multiple actions with different intervals?

Comment: @JacobHigs Caius is basically saying that, but also saying that you can set up multiple `mod` checks to do things at multiple different intervals. You could do `_expCheck++; if ((_expCheckAddItems = _expCheck % 10) == 0) { AddItems(); } else if ((_expCheckProcessItems = _expCheck % 50) == 0) { ProcessItems(); } else { CleanUp(); }` So your `_expCheck` is the running aggregate and you `mod` the value for your staggered processing functions.

Comment: "I have two timers which are working on the application. One is firing when a new message is received" - that's a confusing statement. A timer fires when its interval elapses, not when a message is received.

Comment: @ScottHannen: Let me rephrase that first timer will elapse as per the interval to check if there is a new message not when new message arrives.

Comment: Is this correct: You're receiving messages, and then at regular intervals you want to process the messages. If, during that time, you received the same message twice, you only want to process it once. Is that right?

Comment: Yes so for that I am not processing every new message coming but first I am storing that message in a dictionary. And if the next message is different from the old message then only I am processing that old message and adding the new message in the dict. But sometimes we will not get new message for long time because of that the old message is stuck for long time in the dict. For that I want to create another timer which will elapsed and then check if any message in the dict is too old to remain in the dict. If it is old then remove from dict and process that message.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments you want to

- process messages at regular intervals - collect messages for 30 seconds before processing them.
- when that interval elapses, you may have received the same message twice, but you only want to process it once.

That's easier if you manage duplicate messages as you process them, not as you receive them.

As messages come in, insert them into a `ConcurrentQueue<Message>` instead of a dictionary. At this step it doesn't matter if there are duplicates.

Set your 30-second timer. You only need one timer. When the timer elapses, read everything from the queue. It's unclear how you recognize duplicate messages, but this is the place to do it.

For example, if `Message` overrides `Equals` so that identical messages are "equal", you could use a [`Hashset<Message>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1). It's a collection that ignores added items if they are already in the collection.

```
void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var messagesFromQueue = DequeueUniqueMessages(messageQueue);
    DoWhateverWithTheMessages(messagesFromQueue);
}

IEnumerable<Message> DequeueUniqueMessages(ConcurrentQueue<Message> messageQueue)
{
    var result = new HashSet<Message>();
    while (messageQueue.TryDequeue(out Message dequeued))
        result.Add(dequeued);
    return result;
}
```

Or if it doesn't or shouldn't override `Equals` you could define a custom [`IEqualityComparer<Message>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1) and use this overload:

```
var result = new HashSet<Message>(new YourCustomMessageComparer());
```

Pass your `ConcurrentQueue` to that method, and you get back a set of messages. This way they're processed first-in-first-out, and you won't get tripped up even if you're still adding new messages to the queue while you're reading from the queue.

Comment: I will not get second new message till I am done with the first message either processing it or saving it in dict. And I have a property using which I can check whether two messages are same or not.

Comment: That's okay. It still works if the messages come in one at a time. I just figured you wanted to account for concurrency because you used `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: But my concern is how to trigger and remove messages from the dictionary which are there for a very long time.

Comment: Using the example above, no messages will remain in the queue for more than 30 seconds. Your timer elapses, you get the messages from the queue, and now it's empty. All of the messages to process are in the `Hashset`, they're unique, and you can process them.

Comment: Problem is how HashSet will get triggered? If you are thinking of using first timer elapsing thats the problem that timer is has very less interval time. Thats why I didnt want to use that timer as trigger and therefore dont want to check the hashset/dict again and again. Thats why I thought of creating the new timer with slightly large interval time.

Comment: I guess that puts me in the same boat as everyone else. I don't get why there are two timers. You receive messages whenever you receive them, and every 30 seconds you process what you have received while eliminating duplicates that arrived during those 30 seconds. I added a little more detail to the answer.